# How to display two separate graph in one chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I have an SSRS report which has two datasets (`ds1` and `ds2`) which calls to a table (`tbl1`):

```
Date        LastWeekEMROrders   LastWeekAccLabOrders    LastWeekLabResults  LastWeekPendingProcessing
2014-06-07  23125               21711                   46881               1414
2014-06-14  24963               21551                   44372               3412
```

The first dataset takes the last week ending date (6/14) and displays in a chart with this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
      ,[LastWeekEMROrders]
      ,[LastWeekAccLabOrders]
      ,[LastWeekLabResults]
  FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl1]
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

The second dataset takes the week ending prior to last week (6/7) and displays in another chart with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [Date]
      ,[LastWeekEMROrders]
      ,[LastWeekAccLabOrders]
      ,[LastWeekLabResults]
      ,[LastWeekPendingProcessing],
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
      FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl1]
      ) AS d
  WHERE d.RowNumber = 2;
```

The two queries displays two different charts:

[image]

What is the best way to combine the both queries or through SSRS so I can add both in one chart like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use a single dataset - Assuming each row corresponds to a week

`SELECT TOP 2 [Date]
      ,[LastWeekEMROrders]
      ,[LastWeekAccLabOrders]
      ,[LastWeekLabResults]
  FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl1]
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC`

Set this dataset to one of the charts and you would see the result that your expecting.